# Replace SQL Exception with empty object

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I use this SQL query to get simple object:

```
@Override
    public Optional<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransactionByWpfPaymentId(Integer id) {
        String hql = "SELECT t FROM " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " t " 
                + " WHERE wppt.wpf_payment_id = :id ";
        TypedQuery<PaymentTransactions> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, PaymentTransactions.class).setParameter("id", id);
        List<PaymentTransactions> wpfPayments = query.getResultList();
        return wpfPayments.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(wpfPayments.get(0));
    }
```

I use this End point

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<PaymentTransactionsDTO>> getWpf_reference_transactions(@PathVariable String id) throws NumberFormatException, Exception {

        Optional<PaymentTransactions> tnx = wpfPaymentsService.paymentTransactionByWpfPaymentId(Integer.parseInt(id));

        if(tnx.get().getId() != 0) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(transactionService
                    .get(Integer.valueOf(tnx.get().getId())).stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        } 

        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
```

But when the database is empty I get `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present`. Is there a way to return just empty object without this exception?

Comment: I also added a simplification for the Collectors.toList part, which seems isn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Optional.get()` will throw `NoSuchElementException - if there is no value present`, so use `isPresent` to know the value is present in optional or not

```
if(tnx.isPresent() && tnx.get().getId() != 0) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(transactionService
                .get(Integer.valueOf(tnx.get().getId())).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    } 

    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your return statement using

```
return tnx.map(PaymentTransactions::getId)
          .filter(id -> id != 0)
          .map(id -> transactionService.get(id)
                                       .stream()
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList()))
          .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
          .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

For a cleaner approach.

Also, this

```
id -> transactionService.get(id)
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()
```

can become

```
id -> new ArrayList<>(transactionService.get(id)))
```

and so you have

```
tnx.map(Transaction::getId)
   .filter(id -> id != 0)
   .map(id -> new ArrayList<>(transactionService.get(id)))
   .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
   .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

I also doubt you need

```
id -> new ArrayList<>(transactionService.get(id))
```

Instead, this is sufficient

```
id -> transactionService.get(id)
```

Because you cannot touch that `List` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Wherever your exception originates from, wrap it in a `try/catch` block, as follows:

```
try {
    <code that throws exception>
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    return new MyObject();
}
```